# Scrollspy + iframe issue

Tags: iframe, bootstrap-4, embed, smooth-scrolling, scrollspy

I have found a bit of an issue, but can't find a solution.
I have been using ScrollSpy and a some smooth-scrolling, but it seems that if I add a iframe, Scrollspy doesn't seem to work how I want it to.

Here is a pen where it isn't working: https://codepen.io/samrbrown/pen/NMraQB

Here is a pen here I have removed just the iframe and it's working how I want: https://codepen.io/samrbrown/pen/pVEdXo

Here is the code for the iframe:

```
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!